# How to RoundUp in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am creating a calculator using and my result need to be rounded-up. How do I do that?

The only thing I can do is to round the result but not round-up.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, you need to use:
Math.Ceiling(Number)    Returns the smallest integer value that is greater than or equal to the specified number.